# View an image with xamarin forms

Tags: c#, image, file, xamarin.forms, path

I should be viewing an image from internal memory.

Code:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    static readonly File file = new File(Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures), "tmp.jpg");

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool exists = file.Exists(); // exists = true
        ImageExample.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(file.Path);
    }
}
```

xaml:

```
<StackLayout>
    <Button HeightRequest="100" 
            WidthRequest="200"
            HorizontalOptions="Center" 
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
    <Image x:Name="ImageExample" 
           HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
           VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
           WidthRequest="200" 
           HeightRequest="100"/>
</StackLayout>
```

Why is the image not displayed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show your xaml.

Comment: Do you have any error messages in VS output window? Something about "...not found" etc.?

Comment: sorry the errors is  W/ImageView( 9011): resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/tmp.jpg

Comment: Try using `Image.UriSource=file.Path;`

Comment: Try `ImageExample.Source = "file://" + file.Path;`

Comment: sorry not work..

Comment: is `/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/tmp.jpg` a valid image file?

Comment: yes is a valid imge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. It looks like your app doesn't have permissions to read from file storage.

You should add the line

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

into the `AndroidManifest.xml` file (located in `Properties` subfolder of the `<your-app-name>.Android` folder).

Also, you should add to the `MainActivity.cs` file:

```
 using Android;
 using Android.Support.V4.App;
 .... 
    const int OurRequest = 2;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        ....
        var permission = new string[1];
        if (Android.Support.V4.Content.ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage) != Permission.Granted)
        {
            permission[0] = Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage;
            ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, permission, OurRequest);
        }
```

Now if you run the app, it will ask about permission and (in case of positive answer, obviously) image will be loaded.